# create type in sql server with allowed values

Tags: sql-server, types, sql-server-2012

I want to create a type in sql-server which is similar to DOMAIN in postgresql.

```
CREATE DOMAIN degree_level NVARCHAR(10)
CONSTRAINT degree_level_test
CHECK (VALUES IN (’Bachelors’, ’Masters’, ’Doctorate’))
```

Note: I know this query is not correct.

Is it possible to create such types in SQL-server?

Comment: In sql server we have User defined types have a look [`User defined Types`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131086.aspx) and also for [`User Defined Table/Column Types`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131076.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In sql Server you will need to do this in two steps

1) Create a Type

2) Create a constraint

**Create A TYPE**

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.degree_level FROM NVARCHAR(10)
GO
```

**Create a Constraint on Table Level**

```
CREATE TABLE Type_Test_Table
(
ID INT ,
Type_Column degree_level
CHECK (Type_Column IN( 'Bachelors' , 'Masters' ,'Doctorate'))
)
GO
```

**Test**

```
INSERT INTO Type_Test_Table VALUES (1, 'Bachelors')   --<-- Success
GO
INSERT INTO Type_Test_Table VALUES (2, 'Masters')     --<-- Success
GO
INSERT INTO Type_Test_Table VALUES (3, 'Doctorate')   --<-- Success
GO
INSERT INTO Type_Test_Table VALUES (4, 'Other Val')   --<-- Fail
GO
```

Comment: thanks but is it possible to check constraints in type creation?

Comment: Not a problem, yes you can create a constraint in a UDF Type only if its a `TABLE TYPE`. And you can accept the answer if it helped you :)