# What's difference between CONSTRAINT CHECK and CREATE TYPE CHECK

Tags: sql, sql-server

**CONSTRAINT  CHECK :**

```
CREATE TABLE sales
(ord INTEGER NOT NULL,
ship INTEGER NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE sales
ADD CONSTRAINT order_check CHECK(ord < 10);
```

Example from [How enable all CONSTRAINT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176445/how-enable-all-constraint)

**CREATE TYPE**

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.degree_level FROM NVARCHAR(10)
GO
Create a Constraint on Table Level

CREATE TABLE Type_Test_Table
(
ID INT ,
Type_Column degree_level
CHECK (Type_Column IN( 'Bachelors' , 'Masters' ,'Doctorate'))
)
GO
```

Example from
[create type in sql server with allowed values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21803724/create-type-in-sql-server-with-allowed-values)

**Question:**

What's the difference between these methods ? 
Why the different functional for one purpose?